# Plesk DNS Not Working

Tags: dns, plesk

> Missing nameservers reported by parent

and

> Stealth NS records sent

```
 http://www.intodns.com/sitemetre.net
```

if i check this giving some error seem with "red"
what i must do?

Comment: Could you please list whole zone of your domain?

Answer (score 0):

Stealth NS records are sent when the authoritative zone file has been delegated to a different nameserver. ([source](http://massivedns.com/blog/dns-report-tutorials/what-are-stealth-ns-records/))

[image]